# Why are result sets so large?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc

Why are result sets from data bases so large?  I typically get result sets that are around a million rows, each of which contains a couple of numerics, a varchar(75), a big int...whatever.  Probably not much more than 100 bytes per row.  And yet it takes up 6 GB!  Is this typical behavior?  My stack is Postgres + JDBC + Spring - I don't have any experience with other technologies.

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific with your whole question for anyone to give you a good answer.

What does "whatever" mean?  "Probably" not much more than 100B/row?  Do the actual math and then ask your question.

Comment: What's the reason that you copy the entire DB table into Java's memory? There may be much better solutions for what you're trying to achieve. For example, processing in batches or per-row basis, or displaying in a paginated view.

Comment: How are you measuring that "it takes up 6 GB"?

Answer (score 2):

The `java.sql.ResultSet` itself will typically only have a couple dozen rows of data buffered at any time (configurable).

Now if you load all those rows into memory as Java objects, then you'll see large amounts of memory used. A `String`, for instance, has two bytes per char, two objects headers, an offset, two lengths and a cached hash value. `BigInteger` is similar. It all adds up. Use a profiler.

You might have better luck with a cached row set. That or don't load the entire set of results at once.

Answer (score 1):

We're gonna need to see a Query to see why it's so big. Maybe you're not joining tables right.
(I wish I could comment that...)

Comment: Congratulations! You can now comment! :)

Comment: Yaaaaaay~ It's a bit frustrating to go around the site looking for buttons which I swear to have seen before...

Comment: When below 50 rep, commenting on other's posts is only possible in your own questions.